# Convert this code ID based to work for classnames

Tags: javascript, class

I need some overflow scroll element in a mobile website and few versions, for example, of Android wont deal with them..

This code enables the touch scrolling:

```
function touchScroll(id){
            if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
                var el=document.getElementById(id);
                var scrollStartPos=0;
                document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
                    scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
                    event.preventDefault();
                },false);

                document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
                    this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;
                    event.preventDefault();
                },false);
            }
        }
        touchScroll('cHolder');
```

I tested it and it works for #cHolder. But how do i need to alter it (I wouldn't mind using jquery syntax) so it works for classes? Thing is that I have multiple containers like this in my layout

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
function touchScroll(id) {
    if (isTouchDevice()) { //if touch events exist...
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
        var scrollStartPos = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            els[i].addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
                scrollStartPos = this.scrollTop + event.touches[0].pageY;
                event.preventDefault();
            }, false);

            els[i].addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
                this.scrollTop = scrollStartPos - event.touches[0].pageY;
                event.preventDefault();
            }, false);
        }
    }
}
touchScroll('cHolder');
```

Comment: Thanks! allthough i just realised this won't work for horizontal scrolling... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just replace `var el=document.getElementById(id)` with a jQuery syntax:

```
var el = $(id).get(0);
```

Which will actually create a jQuery selector, then fetch the DOM-object.

Then I'd suggest you replace `document.getElementById(id)` on line 5 and 9 with `el`

Then you can pass any selector into the function, and it will get that element!

Comment: What makes you think the OP uses jQuery? *"I wouldn't mind using jquery syntax"* could mean anything tbh. Besides, this is not explaining how to select elements by *class*.